# how to connect apache ignite by redis's interface

Tags: redis, ignite

i want connect apache ignite from nodejs by redis's interface
in ignite config, i add bellow xml defintion in config-default.xml:

```
<property name="connectorConfiguration">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ConnectorConfiguration">
        <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="port" value="6379"/>
    </bean>
</property>
```

and run ignite.bat (testing platform in win7 64bit)

```
console message seeming running fine:
[15:59:09] To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}
[15:59:09]
[15:59:09] Ignite node started OK (id=b58f9f35)
[15:59:09] Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=4, heap=1.0GB]
```

when test a nodejs code such as:

```
var redis = require("redis");
var client = redis.createClient({detect_buffers: true}); 
client.get("test", function (err, reply) {
    if(err == null){
        console.log('reply:'+reply);
    }
    else{
        console.log('error:'+err);
    }
});
client.quit();
```

got a error message in nodejs

```
vents.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
AbortError: Ready check failed: Stream connection ended and command aborted. It might have been processed.
    at RedisClient.flush_and_error (d:\APP\nodejs\mcanserver\node_modules\redis\index.js:362:23)
    at RedisClient.connection_gone (d:\APP\nodejs\mcanserver\node_modules\redis\index.js:597:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (d:\APP\nodejs\mcanserver\node_modules\redis\index.js:293:14)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
AbortError
```

and errors in ignite console:

```
[16:08:59,809][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#36][GridTcpRestProtocol] Fail
ed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNio
ClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=14 lim=14 cap=8192], super=Abs
tractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=
0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-tcp-rest-0, igniteInstanc
eName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1424564915, interrupted=false, runner=grid-
nio-worker-tcp-rest-0-#36]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outR
ecovery=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:6379, rmtAddr=/127.0.
0.1:18970, createTime=1527667738762, closeTime=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd=14, byt
esSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=14, sndSchedTime=1527667738762, lastSndTime=1527667738762,
 lastRcvTime=1527667738762, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[
GridNioCodecFilter [parser=GridTcpRestParser [jdkMarshaller=JdkMarshaller [], ro
uterClient=false], directMode=false]], accepted=true]]]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.ignite.internal.
processors.rest.protocols.tcp.redis.GridRedisCommand.INFO
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.redis.GridRe
disCommand.valueOf(GridRedisCommand.java:26)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.redis.GridRe
disMessage.command(GridRedisMessage.java:124)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.redis.GridRe
disNioListener.onMessage(GridRedisNioListener.java:132)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestN
ioListener.onMessage(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:193)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.tcp.GridTcpRestN
ioListener.onMessage(GridTcpRestNioListener.java:94)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onM
essageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:279)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessa
geReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:109)
```

i need help to known what's happen? and how to fixed this error, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your client uses a command INFO which isn't implemented by Apache Ignite. Is it possible to try alternative client or maybe a memcached client? Note that the latter has binary and text forms, only one of which is supported.

Comment: i want using apache ignite for corss platform in-memroy cache (redis/ignite client/restful ..), is not a good idea to use this?

Comment: I think you should use a different client. By the way, there should be a node.js client for Apache Ignite after 2.5 is released.

Answer (score 0):

just ran into the same issue with node.js redis client.. indeed, INFO operation is not supported by Apache Ignite, and node redis client uses it to check if Redis is ready to serve queries.. a workaround is to turn it off:

```
redis.createClient({no_ready_check: true});
```